# How do I connect from Azure Data Factory to a Firebird/InterBase (Syntess) database?

Tags: odbc, connection-string, azure-data-factory, firebird, syntess

In ADF, I have created a pipeline. The source is an ODBC table or query. The next step is to create a Linked Service. The Integration Runtime has been created and selected as you can see below.

Now comes the question: What connection string am I supposed to enter?

Attempts with `Server=192.168.1.35; Database=dbname;DSN=IP/port;UID=userId;PWD=password;` resulted in  `ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

[image: Azure New linked service (ODBC) page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below format, fill in the values and test the connection:

`DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;UID=[userid];PWD=[password];DBNAME=[IP and optionally /port]:[C:\example\atrium.FDB]`