# Azure Data Factory and Firebird database via ODBC connection problem

Tags: odbc, azure-data-factory, firebird

Does anyone connect successfully to Firebird DB using DataFactory via predefined ODBC driver as a source? I got an error:

```
Error code: 9603 
Details:ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found
```

Here is my .json:

```
{
"name": "Odbc_firebird",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "Odbc",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Server=192.168.1.1;Port=3050;Pooling=True; Database=C:\\db\\database.fdb",
        "authenticationType": "Basic",
        "userName": "SYSDBA",
        "encryptedCredential": "****"
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "integrationRuntimeOnPremise",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
}
```

I guess, that ADF do not have embedded Firebird driver or I put bad Driver name, but I could be wrong. Maybe there is another way to config it? IR responds correctly, I can ping my destination machine with tcping tool on 3050 port via IR.

Comment: Check if this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451070/how-do-i-connect-from-azure-data-factory-to-a-firebird-interbase-syntess-datab) helps you.

Comment: It does not work - I previously asked about the same in this thread, my post was deleted. So I created new one.